# symfony2 routing parameters and request

Tags: symfony

I have this route

```
edit_project:
    pattern:  /edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: CpjProjectsBundle:Project:edit }
    requirements:
        id: \d+
```

and this is the controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request)
{

}
```

inside the controller I'm unable to receive id

```
$this->query->get('id'); //empty
```

if I change the method signature, it works:

```
public function editAction($id)
```

but I need the Request to handle the form, usualy in this way

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

any suggestion for a workaround?
many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final URL looks like this: `http://my.domain.com/edit/123` so there is no *query* part of URL (`...?id=123`). You should accept both the `Request` object and `id` as arguments of your function:

```
 public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
 {
     var_dump($request, $id);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using that url if you want access to the id you will pass it as another parameter to your function. But it seems like you may want to get the Project entity associated with that id. You can save a step in your controller and have symfony look it up for you by type hinting the  `$id` variable like so:

```
<?php
namespace Cpj\ProjectsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Cpj\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Project;
//Other use statements

class PrjectController extends Controller
{

    public function editAction(Request $request, Project $id)
    {
        var_dump($id);
        // This will be and instance of Cpj\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Project
        //if you need the actual ID of it you can do the following
        $realID = $id->getId()
    }
}
```